# How to pause/resume the upload/download to/from WebDav server?

Tags: upload, download, webdav, resume

I have used JackRabbit library to connect to WebDav server. I can successfully upload/download files to/from WebDav server. But, I'm having problem(actually I have no idea) with pausing/resume of upload/download.

Can anyone please help me with implementing pausing/resuming of upload/download to WebDav server?

Thanks, 
Satish

Answer (score 1):

Now, I have the answer. Thought it might be useful to someone having the same problem. Pausing/resuming doesn't depends on server. It has to be done based on HTTP protocol. Please refer HTTP protocol specifications for more details.